# TypeError: register_tortoise() got an unexpected keyword argument 'add_exeption_handlers'

Tags: fastapi, testdriven.io

Code was copies from https://testdriven.io/courses/tdd-fastapi/postgres-setup/ but it show an exeption while running with uvicorn

```js
import os

from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends
from tortoise.contrib.fastapi import register_tortoise

from app.config import get_settings, Settings


app = FastAPI()


register_tortoise(
    app,
    db_url=os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL"),
    modules={"models": ["app.models.tortoise"]},
    generate_schemas=True,
    add_exeption_handlers=True,
)


@app.get("/ping")
async def pong(settings: Settings = Depends(get_settings)):
    return {
        "ping": "pong!",
        "environment": settings.environment,
        "testing": settings.testing
    }
```

Comment: Typo `add_exeption_handlers`. Use `add_exception_handlers`

Comment: Omg... Thank you a lot!